# Case Study: Classifying the origin of a word

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics

Let's say we have a **Country 'A'** that spoke a **Language 'A'**.
In **Language 'A'** (**LA**) they had the word "*Shamish*" (*IPA*: /ʃamɪʃ/)

A **Language 'X'** (**LX**) is gaining ground in **Country 'A'** and they have the same word with the ***same meaning*** but with one difference. The ending "sh" is replaced by an "s" ==> "*Shamish*" --> "*Shamis*" (*IPA*: /ʃamɪs/)

**Country 'A'** now uses "*Shamis*" in **LA** but how is this "new" word classified ?!

Let's assume that these two "*similar*" words are independent from each other and their formation was merely out of luck.

-Could it be considered that:

- it might be a natural change ?
- a replacement from **LX**, therefore "*Shamis*" in **LA** is now a
  borrowed word
- an influence from **LX**'s inflection (using "s" instead of "sh") so
  "*Shamis*" in **LA** is still an **LA** term but with **LX** features
- ...

Comment: Are you saying two physically close languages have two words that are identical in meaning, and almost identical in shape, and that's a **coincidence**? How likely is this, and how can you generalize from a coincidence?

Comment: If it’s a natural change, you’d expect to find other examples that fit the same pattern (e.g., final _-ish_ > _-is_ in general). Since our source material here is just one word, we have no way of telling whether this is the case. It could be either of the three options you list, then.

Comment: @jlawler I agree, but it's hypothetical ! I would be interested to know how things would be if they were related as well !

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes ofc, but even if other words followed this same pattern, we could not disclose the possibility of being an influence from **LX** ! (on a greater number of words, i guess a rough estimation would be made depending on the number of newly introduced words...)

Comment: @PrimataLógico No, you could never discount influence from language X. But if _-ish_ > _-is_ was a general sound law within the language itself, you wouldn’t have to assume influence either.